# Fow of loading webpage background image

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I have webpage i am using very large size background image for that, the issue is when normally we visit the page it will display website contents and then load the background image.

in my case the situation is different my webpage is waiting untill the background image is loaded and then start displaying the page contents.

I use very simple CSS

```
body{background-image:url('http://www.example.com/myimage.jpg')}
other css goes here....
```

and webpage load flow is

```
Background image load first (webpage display no contents it just load the image)  
     |
then load the contents.
```

I want to **load the contents first and then background image** anybody have idea how to do that. (using simple method) or **asynchronous loading of background-image and contents**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple solution:**

Just add the background image via css on load:

```
// in header of page
window.onload = function(){
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://www.example.com/myimage.jpg')";
}
```

**More complicated solution:**

If you want it to look better, you can add an image element and when it's done loading, fade it into the background (uses jQuery)

```
// in header of page (make sure to include jQuery)
$(window).load(function(){
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "http://www.example.com/myimage.jpg";
    $(img).addClass("bgImgStyle").hide().prependTo("body").fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Thank you PitaJ.. I am sure this will work.. just wanted to know can we do it without javascript..

Comment: @monamona - Don't think there's any way without javascript